# Replacement at the line start JS RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a multiline string for which I need to do the following modification: If a line starts from one or two digits followed by a period, e.g. `1.` or `20.`, that number+period must be replaced with `<li>`.

I've tried to do it with regexp but in my attempts if the number+period occurs in other part of the line than the start), it also gets replaced with `

and that is undesirable.

Could anyone help me with right regexp?

```js
let text =`
1.
Some text here
Any text here
Some text here
2.
Some text here
Any text here 24
Some text here
30.
Some text here 42.
Any text here
Some text here`;
let regex = /[0-9]./g;
let result = text.replace(regex, '<li>');
document.write(result);
```

Comment: One of the reasons I voted to close your answer as "lacks clarity" is because your test example doesn't include an obvious case: a line includes a number followed by a period somewhere other than the start of line. None of the answers, including the accepted one, currently handles this. I've added such a case (`Some text here 42.`) to your sample. You should clarify how it should behave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to replace number with LI and number, use parentheses to create capture group and then reference it with dollar sign:

```
s.replace( /(\d+\.)/g , "<li>$1" )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex must be `let regex = /[0-9]+\./g;`

```js
let text =`
1.
Some text here
Any text here
Some text here
2.
Some text here
Any text here 2400.
Some text here00.
300.
Some text here
Any text here
Some text here`;
let regex = /[0-9]+\./g;
let result = text.replace(regex, '<li>');
document.write(result);
```